# Trouble with joining with select or joining with temporary tables

Tags: mysql

I have five tables

```
orders(order_id,user_id,) 
order_info(id,price,tax,discount)
users(user_id,uadd_id)
user_address(uadd_id,type,city_id)
city_info(city_id,city_name,city_code)
```

I need to obtain a report of orders which include order information from `order_info` table, user_information that usually comes form user table and users shipping and billing address both comes from `user_address` table. The `users.uadd_id` maps with `user_address.id` and the `user_address.type` stores if it is a shipping or billing address. So for the same order I need two rows of the user_address one for shipping and the other for billing. The `city_info` table contains the details of city and should be joined with the user address table to get the complete information of the user address.

I tried this query

```
select o.*,oi.*,billing_info.name as binfo_name,shipping_info.name_name
from order o 
left join order_info oi on o.order_id = oi.id
left join (
          select * from user u1 
          left join user_address ua1 on ua1.uadd_id = u1.uadd_id 
          left join city_info ci1 on ua1.city_id = ci1.city_id where ua1.type = 'billing') as billing_info 
       on billing_info.user_id = o.user_id
left join (select * from user u2 
           left join user_address ua2 on ua2.uadd_id = u2.uadd_id 
           left join city_info ci2 on ua2.city_id = ci2.city_id  
           where ua1.type = 'shipping' ) as shipping_info 
                                        on shipping_info.user_id = o.user_id
where 1;
```

(I have selected other columns for both billing_info and shipping_info) This works and i can get both billing and shipping info but the problem is the query takes a lot of time ( almost 2 seconds) to execute. I have a large set of data in all the tables. so i needed to do something else.

I tried temporary table to store all required shipping and billing info and join the order table with these two tables but its still taking a lot of time ( again 2 seconds)
here is how I tried to use the temporary table:

```
create temporary table shipping_info 
       select * from user u1 
       left join user_address ua1 on ua1.uadd_id = u1.uadd_id 
       left join city_info ci1 on ua1.city_id = ci1.city_id 
       where ua1.type = 'billing';

create temporary table billing_info 
       select * from user u1 
       left join user_address ua1 on ua1.uadd_id = u1.uadd_id 
       left join city_info ci1 on ua1.city_id = ci1.city_id 
       where ua1.type = 'shipping';

select o.*,oi.*,billing_info.name as binfo_name,shipping_info.name_name
from order o 
left join order_info oi on o.order_id = oi.id
left join shipping_info on shipping_info.user_id = o.user_id
left join billing_info on billing_info.user_id = o.user_id
where 1;
```

Can anyone help me on how i can do this efficiently using any of the above ways or some other way?

If any errors in query due to syntax, please neglect that for now since i had to change the actual query to shorten wherever possible red data and use this temporary table to join with other table to select the required data.

Comment: It would be nice if you added the definitions of your tables (including the indexes).

Comment: and when you say *"large tables"*, how large do you mean?

Comment: Each table has minimum of 20000 rows , and actully i am not selecting all data from all tables its filtered in the where condition so the time taken that i mentioned is for fetching 5000 rows of data which i guess shouldn't take so much time.

Comment: Question cannot be answered without the table definition, voting to close.